# Camera Intent in Android for Work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-for-work

I'm firing a Camera Intent to take photos with the Camera Application. It's working as expected in my default version of the App.

I've implemented the same code for `"Android for Work"` version of my application which ended up with a weird behaviour. Normally, according to `"Android for Work"` videos, an Intent cannot be handled if it's in a different profile. E.g, if I don't have a Camera Application installed in my Work Profile, Camera Intent should be null after it's resolved, which is expected.

But in my case, Camera Intent is handled by the Camera Application installed in my default user profile (`Work Profile` doesn't have a Camera Application). And when the picture is taken, it comes back to `onActivityResult` with a `resultCode` `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

So, my questions is, How can I distinguish the User's `Real Cancel Event` and this situation ? Both of them has the same result, `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`

Here is the Code Below showing how I fire the Camera Intent.

```
/* Create Camera Intent */
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

/* Check if the Camera Intent is Available */
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) == null) {

    /* Notify User in Error Case */
    UIUtils.notifyUser(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.no_camera_application_found));

} else {

    /* Create a new File with Random Photo Name */
    takenPhoto = new File(FileUtils.getExternalPhotoCacheDirectory(), generatePhotoName());
    takenPhoto.createNewFile();

    /* Create Uri to send to within the Intent */
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(takenPhoto);

    /* Set Photo destination File Uri */
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    /* Start Activity for Result */
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
 }
```

**EDIT :** Here some Screen Shots from my admin panel.
[image: Cross Profile Restrictions]
[image: Applications Allowed in Work Profile]

Comment: You can handle if any application can handle the intent ,before firing it

Comment: @sadeghsaati that's what I do with `resolveActiivty` in if statement in the first hand. But It doesn't return null, unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [setCameraDisabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setCameraDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)) method for [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html):

> Called by an application that is administering the device to disable all cameras on the device, **for this user.** After setting this, no applications **running as this user** will be able to access any cameras on the device.

Hence, only apps running on the work profile will be unable to access the Camera - as it reads, this does not affect the default user profile.

The admin app would need to call [addCrossProfileIntentFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#addCrossProfileIntentFilter(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20int)) with the [FLAG_PARENT_CAN_ACCESS_MANAGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#FLAG_PARENT_CAN_ACCESS_MANAGED) to disable intents from work profile apps being able to be resolved on the parent (default user) apps if they don't want any intents being sent from the Work profile to the user profile.

Now, if you want your app using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to work on a work profile, you can follow these instructions:

Each user on Android has an entirely sandboxed storage space, including public storage directories. This means that the default user profile Camera app cannot read any file directories accessible to a work profile app.

Instead, you need to provide a URI that they can write to such as one returned by a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) as explained in the [file sharing training](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

```
/* Create a new File with Random Photo Name */
takenPhoto = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), generatePhotoName());
takenPhoto.createNewFile();

/* Create Uri to send to within the Intent */
Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
    "your.authority.read.the.docs", takenPhoto);

/* Set Photo destination File Uri */
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

Important to note that the file here is being saved to your app's cache directory - not to a public storage location.

You'll also need to include Uri based permissions as well:

```
cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
cameraIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri(null, outputFileUri));
```

Usually, only the Uri included in `setData(uri)` is given permission, but any Uri also included in clip data will be given permission as well, allowing the Camera app the ability to read and write your `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` Uri.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's correct, that the Work and Default user's storages are separated, but for "Android For Work" they both run at the same time. Which still doesn't let them to write each other's storage space. That's not my concern.

Because, if the Camera app for Work Profile is not installed (restricted by admin), then I don't want user to be able to access to Default camera app. If it's restricted, user should not be able to use it. But when I launch the intent, Work profile can still access to Application in Default profile, that's not expected.

Comment: So, either user should not have access to Default Camera App, when it's restricted, or if it cannot be blocked, resulCode returned to activity should be different than the Activity.RESULT_CANCELED so I can tell user why they couldn't take a photo.

Comment: FYI, If I enable Camera option from admin panel (which ends up with installing the Camera app to Work Profile), then It works as expected.

Comment: so, shouldn't that line return null when there is no Camera App in Work Profile ? `cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()`

Comment: But they do have access to the default camera app and, if you use the code I provide, you can take pictures from there and give them to your work profile app.

Comment: But isn't that against to idea of separating profiles and providing them "Same Applications but in different work spaces" ? If the Camera App is restricted by admin, then user should not have access to it via my application. am I missing something ?

Comment: Added some comments on what disabling the camera does and the separate control for disabling cross user intents

Comment: Thanks for the details. See my edit for attached ScreenShots from my admin console. As in the screen shots, pretty much everything is disabled in the console regarding to Camera and Cross Profile Access. So it seems like, they couldn't handle these restrictions correctly with`DevicePolicyManager` as it doesn't apply to work profile installed in the device. Might be a bug in their side (Admin App) ?

Comment: As `addCrossProfileIntentFilter` takes an exact <intent-filter>, it may be that 'sharing documents' only involves 'ACTION_SEND` restrictions and `GET_CONTENT`/`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` would not be covered under those restrictions. Obviously from a data protection perspective, reading data from the default user profile doesn't affect the protection of work profile data.

Comment: You might be right about involving `ACTION_SEND` restriction only. Because I just tested `ACTION_SENDTO`, and default user's email app is not prompted from Work Profile App. And tested for file transfer, same result, work profile app can read from the default user's profile, with `GET_CONTENT`. So what would be the solution ? Providing a File Uri that default user Camera App can write to ? So If they want to block camera usage, they can restrict the usage of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. I will contact them as well to see if they think it's security gap or this was their intention.

Comment: @osayilgan - as stated in the answer, you cannot use File Uris across profiles - it must use a solution such as `FileProvider`. Yes, if a Device Administrator wants to lock down the use of `GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, they'd be able to do that.